# Carousel Page xamarin forms display selected item details

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, navigation, carousel

I have this listView which display a bunch of items, and the idea is to click one, navigate to a carousel page and display its details there.

Problem: the carousel page also has to know the position of this item in the main list, and OnSlide must show the next/previous item from this selected one.

Already done:

> ListView successfully populated and displaying selectable items.
>   OnSelectedItem pushAsync navigation to DetailPage and show there its details.

Now the problem has been even being able to populate a carousel page...

Already contacted the Xamarin team and they gladly helped me by sending me «here or to the forums because they couldn't be of any help»... (already tried the forums, been waiting for almost two months now :s, and the work needs to be delivered).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the "easiest" way would be to use a `ListView` and a `CarouselPage` (or `CarouselView` in `Xamarin.Forms` version 2.2+) that are sharing the same `ItemsSource` but using different `DataTemplate`s that are embedded within a `NavigationPage` so you can push/pop of the CarouselPage for *free*.

Within the `ListView.ItemSelected` event, you can set `SelectedItem` of the `CarouselPage` to the be same as the item selected in the `ListView` since they are **sharing the same data source**. Then just push the CarouselPage to be the current Page and you are all done.... ;-)

#### `Xamarin.Forms` 2.1 using `CarouselPage`:

```
var carouselPage = new CarouselPage ();
carouselPage.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate (() => new SaucePage ());
carouselPage.ItemsSource = sauces;

var listView = new ListView (ListViewCachingStrategy.RecycleElement);
listView.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate (() => new HotSauceCell ());
listView.ItemsSource = sauces;
listView.ItemSelected += (object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e) => {
    carouselPage.SelectedItem = e.SelectedItem as Sauce;
    (MainPage as NavigationPage).PushAsync (carouselPage, true);
};
MainPage = new NavigationPage (new ContentPage {
    Content = listView
});
```

#### `Xamarin.Forms` 2.2 Pre-Release using CarouselView:

```
var carouselView = new CarouselView ();
carouselView.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate (() => new SauceView ());
carouselView.ItemsSource = sauces;
var carouselDetailPage = new ContentPage {
    Content = carouselView
};
var listView = new ListView (ListViewCachingStrategy.RecycleElement);
listView.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate (() => new HotSauceCell ());
listView.ItemsSource = sauces;
listView.ItemSelected += (object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e) => {
    carouselView.Position = sauces.IndexOf (e.SelectedItem as Sauce);
    (MainPage as NavigationPage)?.PushAsync (carouselDetailPage, true);
};
MainPage = new NavigationPage (new ContentPage {
    Content = listView
});
```

#### Results in:

[image]

[image]

Note: In `Xamarin.Forms` version 2.2 (currently available via pre-release Nuget) I would highly recommend using `CarouselView`, it is faster, meaner, slicker, happier, ;-) Just embed it your preferred type of `Page` class.

Note: The hot sauce data shown is from https://www.syntaxismyui.com/xamarin-forms-carouselpage-recipe/, I modified his sample to use `DataTemplate` so recycling and data binding is had for free....

Comment: Before anything, thanks for answering. I'm sorry, I'm really new to Xamarin, so this question might seem a bit foolish, but where do I set all the code you wrote in your example using CarouselPage? So far I have the App.cs opening a new MainPage which : from MasterDetailPage and opens as Detail the ListPage. It is in this list page that I'm currently doing most of the heavy view work, with help of MVVM arch, so I'm a bit lost now, as all this is relatively new to me...

Comment: @pemq The original code came from https://www.syntaxismyui.com/xamarin-forms-carouselpage-recipe/ (he has a link to his Github acct on that site)

Comment: ok, found it, so you suggest I do all that where I'm already calling the ListPage, is that it?

Comment: @pemq It is in his "OriginalProject" folder https://github.com/awolf/Xamarin-Forms-InAnger/tree/master/src/OriginalProject

Comment: ok, so I think I got it, when you refer to calling the SausePage(), I should (as adam does) pass the Ad I selected, and instead of using binding properties, I simply set "Text = sauce.Name", correct?

Comment: @pemq if you look at my code sample, I set the `CarouselPage` to be viewed via the `listView.ItemSelected` event...

Comment: oh, ok. In my case, I have already created a DetailPage that inherits from CarouselPage. I can create a new instance of that, pass to its constructor my itemsList (the sauces) and the selected item, received it on the other side, and set the SelectedItem of that on the other side, as I will always access this CarouselPage via clicking on an item from ListView, am I being too confuse? :s

Comment: how come you can use CarouselView? Have just found something about it in XLabs, but can't even access it via VisualStudio...

Comment: @pemq : `CarouselView` is available in Xamarin.Forms 2.2 Pre-Release , but was pulled out in later versions and will be in its own library/Nuget. Either installed the 2.2 pre-release version or you will have to wait for the new release.

Answer (score 1):

Before you push your DetailPage set `CurrentPage`.

```
var detailPage = new CarouselPage();
// ...
detailPage.CurrentPage = index;
Navigation.PushAsync(detailPage);
```

If you load the items later, just introduce another property.